# Tablefootnote in table* environment?

Tags: tables, footnotes, two-column

Is it possible to use the `tablefootnote` package in the `table*` environment? With the following minimal example, I see the footnotemark in the table, but no footnote text

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
c & a\\
d & b\tablefootnote{This is a test}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

In the corresponding single column document with the regular table environment, everything works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\begin{tabular}{ll}
c & a\\
d & b\tablefootnote{This is a test}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` mechanism thereby avoiding the necessity of an extra package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe,lipsum}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{table*}%[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
c & a\\
d & b\footnotemark\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\footnotetext{This is a test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am currently using this method and having problems with the footnotes being on a different page than the table. This is why I am looking for help with other packages.

Comment: @jake If you use `table*` in the first page (where title will come), then the table will go to the second page and foot note will say in the first page. This is expected. Put the table in the second page as I did. `table* isn't allowed in the title page.

Comment: I think the problem is more generalized than just being on the title page. Since table* is a float, it can always move to the next page. Since the footnotemark commands don't know that they are associated with the float, they are left on the previous page. In any case, in my full document, the table in question is not on on a title page, so the title isn't the reason for my problem.